# Select one class within li of 2 classes (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css, class, html-lists

html:

```
    <div id="calendar">
        <li class="day">
            <div class="date">4</div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="event-description">
                    Concert
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#calendar .days li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I want to text underline 4 but it only underlines Concert..
How can I only underline 4 and not underline Concert when I hover over my mouse on li??

Comment: #calendar li.day:hover .date{text-decoration:underline;}

Answer (score 1):

Try this

CSS

```
#calendar li.day:hover .date{text-decoration:underline;}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/cewse1wp/)

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix would be to add in `style=" text-decoration: underline;"` in the div that has the class: "date". But you should do that in a stylesheet if you haven't ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
#calendar li:hover  > .date {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 #calendar .day:hover > .date {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```css
 #calendar .day:hover > .date {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
    <div id="calendar">
        <li class="day">
            <div class="date">4</div>
            <div class="event">
                <div class="event-description">
                    Concert
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
```